# Plotly Dash - serving raw html for use in external site with <iframe>

Tags: python, datatables, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I have a plotly dash server. It is serving pages normally, this is working. I have some other dashboards in other systems that I want to pull in some charts from dash, and embed as an iframe.

This works with **Plots** as they have a **to_html()** that does exactly this. I have a custom route here for getting iframes seperate from the normal page flow.

```
@app.server.route("/iframe/<test_id>")
def serve_iframe(test_id):
   # Create a simple bar chart
   fig = p_go.Figure(p_go.Bar(x=["D", "E", "F"], y=[10, 20, 15]))
   # Convert the figure to HTML
   plot_html = fig.to_html(full_html=False, include_plotlyjs="cdn")
   return plot_html
```

This works.
But what about **Datatables**, and general **dash.html.Div()** elements

```
...
   df = pd.DataFrame(table_data)
   dataTable = dash_table.DataTable(...)
   return dataTable
```

nets me

> TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The return type must be a string, dict, list, tuple with headers or status, Response instance, or WSGI callable, but it was a DataTable.

and say if I was to make that table manually with [dash-html-components](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-html-components)

```
   html.Table([ html.Tr()....]
```

the html responce I get is just a string represnetation of the classes

> "Table([Tr([Th('') "

I need a to_html() method for these elements, but non exists?

Have I gone wrong here by having a seperate route, and bypassing the whole dash rendering system.

I could have my 'iframe' data as actual dash **pages**, and then write some code to hide these from the user in normal use- when acessing the plotly site directly.

Answer (score 1):

so the *Have I gone wrong here by having a seperate route?*,
I guess is right - What does work, is creating my "embedded views" as a normal pages.
I had to do some re-wroking of my stucture. As the main app layout function cannot decern what page it's serving - I used to have navbar logic in there but now I've moved that into each page.

main app.py

```
def create_layout() -> html.Div:
   # Used to have this
   # return html.Div([create_navbar(), dash.page_container])
   # but now it does only this
   return html.Div([dash.page_container])
```

and in each page, that I want to have a navbar on, I do

```
from app import create_navbar

#important to use layout() function and not 'layout =  html.Div(...)'
def layout():  
    return html.Div(
        children=[
            create_navbar(),
            html.Div([....])
```

and any 'Embedded page' I'm using for iframes, just doesn't call create_navbar().

create_navbar() has:

```
 if not page["name"].startswith("Embed")....
```

to not show the *Embedded* pages to users in the Nav on other pages.

So this works so long as the Embedding page has a live link back to the plotly server, which it had to anyway for my first working example.

I saw some methods of doing this with callbacks and `dcc.Location(id='url', refresh=False)` which would set a style on the navbar to hide it, but that seemed messy - I would be sending html data to external sites, only to hide it with css.

What's still missing here I guess is, if I wanted to expport these to a static html files, severing the link and need for the plotly-dash server running. These embedded views in my case have no user interactivity or callbacks, it's a oneshot data grab and display.